# What is Batman's standard loadout and how does he carry it around?

Tags: dc, batman

Batman has an amazingly cool and diverse arsenal. However, his costume appears to suffer from a severe lack of storage space because it has no pockets meaning that he keeps all his tools in his utility belt.

I considered the possibility that he wears an outer set of pants to store tools (and it would be accessible due to its close proximity to his belt), but... just no.

[image]

Comment: It's changed over the years, but in the main it seems to contain a [few standard items](http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/batman/images/d/d7/Whoswho_ubelt.gif/revision/latest?cb=20110520075224) plus whatever crap the writer needs him to have to move the story along.

Comment: There's a more up to date version here; http://i.imgur.com/54t2VyK.jpg

Comment: Timelord technology. Bigger on the inside.

Comment: [The first things he always reaches for when arming himself](http://www.factfiend.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Always-ready.jpg)

Comment: In my imagination, Batman always picks a different arsenal based on what he expects to be up against. It'd be neat if some of the stories actually included him working out what he may or may not need, and showing him turn out to be right (and occasionally way off). But I can't recall this ever happening in the movies.

Comment: [Hammerspace.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Hammerspace)  **Warning!  TV Tropes link!**

Comment: Did you just invent the word "loadout"? what does it mean?

Comment: Loadout is a term I've heard many times, I'm not sure the origin.  As for Batman, I'm quite certain his utility belt is made from the same technology as a Bag of Holding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WikiPedia page on [Batman's utility belt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman%27s_utility_belt) has a decent list of what he may or may not carry around.

The items that are almost guaranteed to be found on every variation are

- Batarangs
- Grappling hook
- Lock picks
- A way to communicate (with the Batcave, at least)

As for the grappling hook, sometimes it shoots directly from the belt, and sometimes it's a collapsible launcher that he stores in or on the belt:

[image]

Sometimes it's a full-size gun that is simply holstered on his belt. You typically find him using a holstered gun in movies, such as the Nolaverse Grapple Gun:

[image]

Like the WikePedia article says, he's likely always carrying something to pick locks, although the picks may be stored somewhere like his gloves, so he can access them even if his hands are cuffed.

His Batarangs also come in many designs, but are generally collapsible and fit within his utility belt or like the Nolanverse suit are small and can be tucked in.

Aside from those three items, his loadout isn't necessarily "standard", but I would also count on something like **smoke pellets** to create cover, something to create a distraction (like **flash pellets/explosive**), and some standard **detective gear**: camera, light source, voice recorder, fingerprinting kit.

Those items are typically found within the utility belt, as well.

For reference, here's some variations of his utility belt (click for full-size):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]